# Can't seem to import a framework into my current project in Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Create a Single View App project called `MyApp`
2. Create a Cocoa Touch Framework project called `MyFramework`

   1. Created a Swift file with a class as `public class FrameworkClass`
3. Dragged `MyFramework.xcodeproj` into `MyApp`'s Project Navigator - This caused Xcode to create a workspace.
4. I added the framework to MyApp.General.EmbeddedBinaries

Now it looks like this so far but I can't seem to import my framework still:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before alt-tabbing Xcode to submit this response, I built on reflex and it turns out that it won't detect the references until you build once.  After that, it should start to be detected by the text editor. 
I was going to delete this question however, I already typed it up anyway so might as well. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps to resolve your problem:

- Choose your project, rather than a specific target, and open the
  `Build Settings` tab.
- In the Other Linker Flags section, add `-ObjC`.

  **If these settings are not visible,** change the filter in the Build Settings bar from `Basic to All`.